# Clustering a heavy task on numpy arrays

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I would like to speed up a slow piece of python/numpy code by dividing a task in separate threads (I have four threads on my laptop, standard Python uses a single one, as you all know).

I think that what my program does *can* be divided in as many threads as necessary, please tell me if that is correct:

1. We have two pictures `A, B` (2 big `numpy arrays` with shape (x, y, d))
2. We multiply A by a variable P, then add the result A' to B, we get `C = np.add(A*P, B)`
3. We make a test on `C`

This is a basic description of the loop that I'd like to divide in four threads. I am thinking of the possibility to divide the numpy arrays `A, B` into four arrays `A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4,` then perform the same operations separately.

***Could you advise some starting point to learn how to do that (website, python library, etc.)***

Thanks

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import Synth, time


width, height = 1644, 1644

colors_filename = "D65_maxVal16_4096_9900_LYVE_D+50.csv"
maxVal = 15

RGB, XYZ, sRGB = Synth.load_RGB_XYZ_RGB2(colors_filename)
SITE = False
tri, indices, simplices = Synth.delaunay(XYZ, SITE)

wave_start, wave_end, steps = 400, 700, 31
CMF = Synth.CMF_1931_2deg(wave_start, wave_end, steps)
Illuminant = Synth.Illuminant_D65(wave_start, wave_end, steps)
Neutral = Synth.Neutral(CMF, Illuminant)

background = Synth.black_bg(CMF, Illuminant, tri, width, height)
layer = np.zeros_like(background)

scales = 3
stars = 1
radius, power = width*5., 2. 

alive = 0

times = 10

for i in xrange(scales):

    stars *= times
    times *= 1.5
    radius /= 10.

    max_z = Synth.half_power_light_spot_dist(radius, power)
    min_z = max_z / 10.
    z_range = max_z-min_z

    print "scale", i, "max / min", max_z, min_z

    # the loop I described starts here
    for j in xrange(int(stars)):

        x, y = np.random.randint(0, width), np.random.randint(0, height)

        linear_progression = float(j)/float(stars)

        z = z_range * (1- linear_progression)

        L = 60

        C = np.random.randint(0,150)
        H = np.random.uniform(0., 360.)

        cieX, cieY, cieZ = Synth.LCH_to_XYZ(L, C, H, Neutral)
        cieXYZ = cieX/cieY, 1., cieZ/cieY

        power_star = np.random.uniform(2, 10)

        star = Synth.Stars_Light(width, height, x, y, z, power_star)

        print "star", j, "on", int(stars),

        precision = 0.01 

        star_copy = star

        star_copy[star < precision] = 0

        star_XYZ = np.multiply(star_copy, cieXYZ)

        # this is the slowest part, what I called the performed "test" between the two pictures A (here "background"), and B (here "star_XYZ"), see below to see what the function "layer_opt_mask" does.  
        P = Synth.layer_opt_mask(background[star_XYZ != 0], layer[star_XYZ != 0], star_XYZ[star_XYZ != 0], tri)

        print "power", P

        print "x, y, z", x, y, z
        print "L, C, H", L, C, H

        if P > 0.:

            non_linear_progression = Synth.L_to_Y(100 * (1-linear_progression))/100. #before it was not (1-linear_progression), but (linear_progression)

            print "LI, NLI", linear_progression, non_linear_progression

            """
            on pourrait ameliorer tout ce systeme la en effacant les donnees sous la limite apres avoir multiplie, ce serait un poil plus long mais ce serait plus logique
            """

            precision = 0.0001

            star[star < precision] = 0

            star = np.multiply(star, cieXYZ)

            layer[star != 0] = np.add(layer[star != 0], P * star[star != 0] * non_linear_progression * 0.5)

            alive += 1

            LEN = len(layer[star != 0])

            print alive, "ALIVE", "mask size:", LEN


        else:

            print "DEAD"

B, P = Synth.background_opt(background, layer, tri)

print "power Back, Front", B, P

image = np.add(B*background, P*layer)
image = np.reshape(image, (width*height, 3))

fname = "scales_"+str(scales)+"_alive_"+str(alive)+"_"+str(start_time)+"_"+str(version)+".pbm"

Synth.make_pbm_Maxval(tri, image, RGB, "RGB_"+fname, height, width, maxVal)
Synth.make_pbm(tri, image, sRGB, "sRGB_"+fname, height, width)

print fname
```

The slowest part is in the function "layer_opt_mask", that I thought to cluster:

```
def layer_opt_mask(background, layer, light, tri):
    """ this function is maximizing the intensity of a new layer "light" on an existing 
background "background" where there's already a layer "layer". The limits of acceptable 
pixels intensities are defined by a set of colorimetric coordinates that form 
a delaunay-tetrahedralized convex hull "tri", the function tri.find_simplex returns -1 
when out of gamut pixels are present.
The objective is to have all the pixels values of the layer "light" inside the gamut 
with a maximal intensity """

    intensity = 0.
    nex = 100.

    #25 iterations might be a lot, it could be less, true
    it = 25

    while it > 0:

        it -= 1
        intensity += nex

        mult = np.multiply(light, intensity)

        test = np.add(mult, layer)
        test = np.add(background, test)

        sh = test.shape[0] / 3

        test = np.reshape(test, (int(sh), 3))

        # This is the slowest part but it is unfortunately absolutely necessary
        tet = np.min(tri.find_simplex(test))


        if tet == -1 and it > 0:
            intensity -= nex
            nex /= 10.

    if intensity > 0.01:
        return intensity
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Could you post some code you have already written?

Comment: First profile  your code to see what takes the most time and optimise it. The operation `C = A*P + B` should be very fast, and I really don't see it being the bottleneck of your code (e.g. 2s for `(1000, 1000, 400)` that take 3GB of RAM each). Otherwise use numexpr or Cython to speed up such operations.  There is a number of things you could do before threading. Also a number of matrix operations are naturally multithreaded if you compile numpy with an optimised BLAS (e.g. OpenBLAS, etc)

Comment: As much as I think it's fun to code for parallel processing, @rth is probably correct on this one, and multiprocessing might actually slow down your code. The only case I can imagine it being significantly faster is if you have hundreds of this same operation to carry out, spawning multiple processes and giving them a list of filenames to run the calculation on.

Comment: OK I added my code, but it is a bit obscure I am afraid, because it's using my own library Synth